# Effects of legalizing human meat and how to suppress criminal organizations selling it

Tags: humans, economy, culture, politics, humanoid

Inside the citadel we see many creatures living together, they don't do so because they all love each other and the citadel has achieved not only the end to racism but also inter species peace but because this is the most advanced city in the world with the best medicine, education, infrastructure and defense.

In this feudal era the citadel thrives by being the center of world's economy. No king, imperator or dictator has ever been able to invade and take down the citadel because it is completely self sufficient and does not need anything from outside to survive.

Trading is vital for economic development in the sense of bringing new commodities and allowing the citizens to live in luxury, but if the citadel was to be sieged, everyone would survive just fine.

Sometimes when a really powerful a warlord inspired by preposterous courage tries to attack the citadel or starts killing traders traveling to visit the citadel, we just bribe warriors and assassins from the outside to cause havoc in the attacking city and slaughtering their civilians. Or we just catapult suicidal outsiders which we paid their family riches in order to get their sons to be infected with the black plague and then become a human bio-weapon to be launched in the air on enemy cities.

Burning down crops and forests, poisoning rivers and torturing princes has always been a good method of maintain peace.

The citadel has no death penalty for its citizens, we don't even have a prison, criminals are turned into slaves or in the worst case, really dangerous criminals are  exiled. Because living outside the citadel is way worse than death. In some particular cases non-lethal torture is also used, but it is fairly uncommon.

We also do not have racial or species laws, equality allows everyone to work and pay their taxes.

This to explain that the citadel is not a humanitarian community of peace lovers dressing in flowers and singing songs of love and praising Jesus.

Taxes are incredibly high in the citadel and everyone loves living there because it's the only safe place to live in and the only place in the world with actual services, kind of like northern Europe where taxes are probably the highest in the world but people enjoy it.

We leaders of  the citadel only care about money, therefore we always choose the more efficient way as long people don't complain too much, because revolts are a waste of time and money.

In the citadel vegetarianism is common practice, an we don't have animal farms because of sanitary reason and because farming animals is not efficient land wise, if we were to introduce livestock farms the people of the citadel would actually starve to death.

But some of the citizens of the most carnivorous spectrum of species enjoy buying meats from traders from time to time. All foreign meat is sanitized and controlled for quality before entering the **Great Trading Palace**

The carnivorous species of the citadel are now demanding human meat and the government is wondering what to do in this situation. Trading happens in the main Trading Pallace but it is hard to stop secret vendors without reading minds, just like it is hard to stop drug vendors in the real world.

Obviously the human meat would come from outside the city gates, but human citizens still don't enjoy the idea of human meat being on the market and they are roughly 11% of the population but 94℅ of humans are against human meat. But the other 8 species of the citadel have mixed opinions, some are on the human side understanding the disgust of finding someone with a decapitated head that looks like you exposed for sale while some don't care or think it would boost the economy and all that matters is that tax payers of the citadel are respected and don't get hurt.

Racism in the citadel is real, just as real as speciesm. But the citizens respect each other in fear of the law and the new generations are starting to be more "rational" and tolerating about species and race differences.

Illegal activities are also real in the citadel, but we try our best to suppress and decrease their rate, apparently deviant behaviour can't be stopped but only slowed.

**The question is:**

Should the citadel legalize the trade of human meat coming from outside the city? If so, how do we avoid revolts?

If not, how would the citadel decrease the rate and development of Mafia selling human meat or what is presumed to be human meat? One could imagine criminals just buying pork chops and then selling them as presumed human meat. And we don't want criminal organizations to make any money, because money is power.

The citadel is a capitalistic republic where people vote, but ultimately the most important thing is self conservation through monetary growth.

Comment: 11% of the population is a large bloc to be upsetting. What is the political structure. Voters?

Comment: a state monopoly, perhaps?

Comment: That's a lot of questions for a site that uses a one-specific-question/one-best-answer model.

Comment: @JBH I only count one question....unless you count how? And how do you justify your answer? As being different questions...

Comment: Please edit this mega question down to what you’re actually asking. The bulk of the backstory is not useful to the answering.

Comment: Illegal things will always exists, along with criminal orgs that sell it. This is because government imposes a lot of quality parameters, or other things that increment the final price of the product. If you can get something cheaper, that is good quality, for business it means more revenue. And business is driven by it

Comment: @SRM I just predicted everyone saying my question lacks details and closing it as opinion based or story based. If anyone doesn't care about details, the question is literary in the title and it's divided by the rest of the post at the end marked with  thicker characters.

Comment: (1) "affects of legalizing human meat" (2) "how to suppress...." (3) Should the citadel legalize..." (4) "what is presumed to be human meat" (and I'm ignoring two specific forms of the more general listed above). VTC until you reduce this post to one and only one question.

Comment: @JBH FINE......

Comment: Nah I wouldn't...

Comment: Cool. You have a good question, you just let yourself run away with asking it. If you're content with the answer you've chosen (we recommend not selecting for 24 hours - human nature is to stop caring about answering after a selection's been made) then we're done. If you're interested in what other answers you might get ... put the necessary stuff back: enough backstory to help us understand, the limitations and restrictions, and one, focused question. I'm happy to VTR if that's where you want to go.

Comment: @RodolfoPenteado no no no, it's a thing!

Comment: do other intelligent species meat get sold ?

Answer (score 4):

**Treat it the same as any other prohibited racist act.**

/Racism in the citadel is real, just as real as speciesm. But the citizens respect each other in fear of the law /

In a society of vegetarians where /we don't have animal farms because of sanitary reason/, wanting to eat humans is just another manifestation of racism.  You note that /new generations are starting to be more "rational"/ as regards racism or speciesism.  Certain groups will then feel increasingly isolated and threatened.  These groups can reinforce the us vs them dichotomy by eating human meat, thus relegating humans to "prey".

Fear of the law is a fine way to get disparate groups to leave each other alone, Saddam Hussein style.  The rulers of the city probably have some method to quash groups which seek power and authority for themselves by participating in forbidden activities like eating humans.  If eating humans is illegal, then fear of the law will prevent it as it does other proscribed activities.

The fact that you have slaves which might be human, but you do not want them used for meat means the law must address this.  Some societies allowed slaves but did not allow owners to kill them.  You could have that law, or allow an owner to kill a slave but not eat the meat.

Answer (score 2):

### "Mafia Mince !  Get your fresh mafia mince here !"

> how would the citadel decrease the rate and development of Mafia selling human meat

Want to be able to slaughter humans and let them be eaten, but don't want to annoy everyone ?

Only criminals can be killed (and that includes tax evaders, lawyers and mime artists in my book) and not only will that discourage the mafia from selling the stuff (because it's not in their interests to encourage this) but it will encourage people to hunt them down !

Give people a tax break for handing in criminals.  Let's be generous.  Extra bonus tax break if they're deemed good meat.

> some are on the human side understanding the disgust of finding someone with a decapitated head that looks like you exposed for sale

So it's only allowed for sale in special shops and no window displays.

It's a win-win.  Unless you're a criminal, of course.

And maybe we might criminalize complaining about the death penalty as well.